# I changed Amazon EC2 instance size but my /dev/nvme0n1p1 partition does not increase in size

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, selenium, memory, amazon-ec2

I originally was running an 8gb size EC2 instance. When doing so, my /dev/nvme0n1p1 looked like this:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  4.4G  3.4G  57% /
```

So, I upgraded to a r6i.large instance, which is 16 gb.  I re-check my /dev/nvme0n1p1 partition, and lo and behold, it hasn't changed in size:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  4.4G  3.4G  57% /
```

When I run `free -h`, however, I get:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        130M         14G        740K        794M         14G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

So maybe the instance has increased in size? I'm confused, as I would expect the `/dev/nvme0n1p1` size now to be around 16gb, not 7.7gb

Selenium is still crashing on me and it appears my partition has not increased in size even though I've gotten an instance with more memory.

Comment: Did you extend the partition after increasing the volume?

Comment: I did not ... do you happen to know how I would do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This matches your case:

> suppose that you have resized the boot volume of an instance, such as a T2 instance, from 8 GB to 16 GB and an additional volume from 8 GB to 30 GB.

So, you need to extend the volume, by following these steps:

[Extend the file system of EBS volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html#extend-file-system-nvme).

EDIT:

Look, you know have a volume of size **16TB** (terrabytes *not* gigabytes). As mentioned already, the volume formatted as MBR.

You need to convert it to a GPT format drive. Follow this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ubuntu-convert-mbr-to-gpt/).

WARNING! Make back-up as might lose your data. [Here's how to create an EBS snapshot](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ubuntu-convert-mbr-to-gpt/)

Alternatively, you can *downsize* the EBS volume, but that's requires a little bit of EBS magic.

```
- Snapshot the volume
- Create a new smaller EBS volume
- Attach the new volume
- Format the new volume
- Mount the new volume
- Copy data from old volume to the new volume
- Prepare the new volume
- Detach and unmount old volume
```

Comment: Thanks!  I followed the instructions but I was unable to grow the partition.  I re-posted a new question here, if you think you might be able to help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72080979/cant-grow-partition-using-sudo-growpart